# Help identifying the type of shelf support

Tags: wood, kitchens, cabinets, shelving, carpentry

please could someone help me identify the type of shelf support in the pic below. This is from a kitchen cabinet shelf, need to order some spares, but can't find anything that resembles it online.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/V12yyz6BoFh1yQsz6

Comment: This looks like a proprietary connector being used in some assembled furniture.  I doubt you will find it for sale separately, and also this is more of a "shopping" question which isn't really on topic for the site.

Comment: Can you remove one shelf and provide good, in-focus, pictures of the hardware that is on the shelf and that is on the cabinet?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are called 'Quick-Connect Fittings' and come in many different types and configurations. Here is an [example](https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/hardware/fasteners/quick-connect-hardware/72014-quick-connect-fittings).